# Django - many-to-many through relationship

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have machinery that work in shifts. Each machinery has its own shifts that can be of different duration. These are the models in Django:

```html
class Shift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Machinery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    shifts = models.ManyToManyField(Shift, through='MachineryShift')


class MachineryShift(models.Model):
    machinery = models.ForeignKey('Machinery')
    shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift')

    shift_start_time = models.TimeField()
    shift_end_time = models.TimeField()
```

I need each Machinery to have its own set of Shifts and these models meet the requirements, but it feels that it's not the best solution.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: why do you feel that? I think it looks good

Comment: yes, it does. but the Shift model doesn't have a strong added value and makes the database more complex. I found the best solution from the answer of @xyres. 
And it also follows the Zen of Python: Simple is better than complex. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `class Shift` is not *actually* required. Since, it's there just to give a shift a name, that can be done in `class MachineryShift` also.

```
class Machinery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MachineryShift(models.Model):
    machinery = models.ForeignKey('Machinery')
    shift = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    shift_start_time = models.TimeField()
    shift_end_time = models.TimeField()
```

This way, you can add as many shifts as you want for a machinery. Each machinery will have its own set of shifts.

Comment: Oh, and I can add a MachineShiftTabularInline in MachineryAdmin and thus define the shifts while defining the Machinery. This is what I was missing! Many thanks!